# Vuejs class component fields undefined

Tags: class, vue.js, methods, data-binding, field

https://jsfiddle.net/78mLj9vb/

```
class App extends Vue {
    message = 'Hello!';
    shrek;//属性 property
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.shrek = "This is my swamp!";//代入-assignment
        //"This is my swamp!"がコンソールで出力されている　Prints as it should
        console.log(this.shrek);
        this.print();
    }

    print(){
        console.log(this.shrek);//[undefined]が出力されている Undefined printed to console
    }
}
```

I'm learning Vuejs with class components and typescript. I do not understand why I can't access the fields of my class within methods. They are always undefined. I have tried doing the initial assignment to the field inline along with the property declaration, and I have also tried doing the assignment in the constructor. I imagine it's the Vuejs data binding mangling the class fields in a way that I do not understand, I have tried accessing them through this.$data to no avail. I understand it's probably not good design to have data that is unrelated to presentation in a component class, but this time around I don't have a database so I'm trying to hard code some data into a class method to fake it, so that I can then loop over the data w/v-for to create a select list. I've included a fiddle that looks nothing like what I'm actually trying to do, but illustrates the "issue" (my lack of understanding really).

How do you declare normal class fields outside of the Vuejs data-binding magic, or alternatively, how do you access the data that has been bound and changed by Vue?

Answer (score 0):

For the best use change you code to this:

```
//...
@Component({
  template: `
    <div>
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ shrek }}</h1>
    </div>

  `
})
class App extends Vue {
  data(){
    return {
       shrek: 'test',
       message: 'Hello world!'
    };
  }
  created(){
    this.shrek = "This is my swamp!";
    console.log(this.shrek);
    this.print();
  }

  print(){
      console.log(this.shrek);
  } 
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
//...
```

On your link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/78mLj9vb/)

Comment: I appreciate it. I've seen this syntax before, but I was hoping to just be able to use class properties as 'data' and class properties with the @Props() annotation as 'props'. What I'm interested in here is why the Vue data binding makes it so that I can't access my class properties (regular class fields) outside of the constructor or the <template></template>.

Comment: I think so, Vue was originally designed for ES5-ES6. Then started working on the use of the TS. But the core cannot be changed. Therefore, it’s difficult to customize in the TS!

Answer (score 0):

After having practiced using Vue for a few more weeks and researching various topics on the internet I have come to the conclusion (which should have been obvious to me at first) that the answer is to use components only for what components are good for. That is to say, if you have some logic that gets gnarly and you want to alleviate it with helper functions, those helper functions can be declared outside the class as regular functions and used within the component code. Another upside of this approach is that if multiple components would get use out of your helper function or initialization code, you can instead move it into a typescript or javascript module and import it into those components that need it.

データ初期化や普通の論理を実施するヘルパー関数をコンポーネント内に置くより別の標準なTypescriptやJavascript関数に置いた方が良さそうです。Vuejsのコンポーネント・クラスの良い点はview作りだけでviewと関係ない論理をコンポーネント以外に置くべきです。それにそうするとその論理を別のファイルに置いてモジュール形で複数のコンポーネントはその論理を使えるようになります。